# Three statuses being returned in Network tab

Tags: javascript

So I am consuming the Domainer API using this JavaScript code in my `script.js`:

```
const DOMAINRURLSTATUS = 'https://domainr.p.mashape.com/v2/status';
const DOMAINRKEY = '<api-key>';

// get data from domainr api
function getDataFromApi(value, callback) {
  const QUERY = {
    'mashape-key': DOMAINRKEY,
    domain: `${value}.com,${value}.net,${value}.org,${value}.biz`
  };
  $.getJSON(DOMAINRURLSTATUS, QUERY, callback);
}

// create the code that will display for the domain availability
function renderResult(result) {
  const OUTPUT = $('#domainContainer');
  OUTPUT.prop('hidden', false);
  // while (result.domain === ".net" || ".com" || ".biz" || ".org"){
  //   return `<div class="domainUnavail">LOADING<span class="sold">LOADING</span></div>`;
  // }
  if (result.summary == 'inactive') {
    return `<div class="domain">${
      result.domain
    }<span class="buyButton"><a href="https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/results.aspx?domain=${
      result.domain
    }" target="_blank">Buy it!</a></span></div>`;
  } else if (result.summary == 'active') {
    return `<div class="domainUnavail">${
      result.domain
    }<span class="sold">Unavailable</span></div>`;
  } else {
    return `<div class="domainUnavail">${
      result.domain
    }<span class="sold">Unavailable</span></div>`;
  }
}
// render results to page (will bring in renderResult code from above.)
function displayDomainResults(data) {
  const RESULTS = data.status.map((item, index) => renderResult(item));
  $('#domainResults').html(RESULTS);
}

// script for random name generation
function get_new_name() {
  const OUTPUT = $('#nameResult');
  OUTPUT.prop('hidden', false);
  $('#nameResult').html(`<img src="ajax-loader.gif">`);
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }

  // get value from drop down
  var minlen = document.getElementById('js-dropValue').value,
    maxlen = document.getElementById('js-dropValue').value,
    param = 'min=' + minlen + '&max=' + maxlen;
  // Get data from name generator
  xmlhttp.open(
    'GET',
    'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://uzby.com/api.php?' + param,
    true
  );
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('nameResult').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    const THISQUERY = xmlhttp.responseText;
    getDataFromApi(THISQUERY, displayDomainResults);
  };
  xmlhttp.send();
  return false;
}
```

I would get three requests on my Network tab and I was unsure why. I tried different refactors until I decided to reach out to the Domainer team and they told me that the problem was with my code and not their API, specifically the `onreadystatechange` in my `XMLHttpRequest` handler.

They said, since I am using jQuery, to use its built-in ajax method instead of using `XMLHttpRequest` directly.

So I followed their suggestion and refactored the code like so:

```
const DOMAINRURLSTATUS = "https://domainr.p.mashape.com/v2/status"
const UZBYURL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://uzby.com/api.php?"
var DOMAINRKEY = config.DOMAINRKEY;

// get data from domainr api
function getDataFromDomainrApi(value, callback) {
  const OUTPUT = $('#domainContainer');
  OUTPUT.prop('hidden', false);
  $('#domainResults').html('<br><img src="ajax-loader-light.gif" alt="ajax-loader">');

  const QUERY = {
    "mashape-key": DOMAINRKEY,
    domain: `${value}.com,${value}.net,${value}.org,${value}.biz`
  }
  $.getJSON(DOMAINRURLSTATUS, QUERY, callback)
  .fail(function(){alert("Domain connection not working?")});
}

// create the code that will display for the domain availability
function renderResult(result) {

  if (result.summary == "inactive") {
    return `<div class="domain">${result.domain}<span class="buyButton"><a href="https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/results.aspx?domain=${result.domain}" target="_blank">Buy it!</a></span></div>`;
  } else if (result.summary == "active") {
    return `<div class="domainUnavail">${result.domain}<span class="sold">Unavailable</span></div>`;
  } else {
    return `<div class="domainUnavail">${result.domain}<span class="sold">Unavailable</span></div>`;
  }
}

// render results to page (will bring in renderResult code from above.)
function displayDomainResults(data) {
  const RESULTS = data.status.map((item, index) => renderResult(item));
  $('#domainResults').html(RESULTS);
}

//Wait for user to click "create my name" button
function watchSubmit() {
  $('.js-search-form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //unhide name section
    $('#domainResults').html("");
    const NAMEOUTPUT = $('#nameResult');
    NAMEOUTPUT.prop('hidden', false);
    // add loading image for latency
    $('#nameResult').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="ajax-loader">');
    // set variables for get request
    var minlen = $('#js-dropValue').val();
    var maxlen = $('#js-dropValue').val();
    var param = `min=${minlen}&max=${maxlen}`;
    //Get random name result
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: `${UZBYURL}${param}`,
      success: function(result) {
        const NAME = result;
        $('#nameResult').html(NAME);
        getDataFromDomainrApi(result, displayDomainResults);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('error loading names');
      }
    });
  });
}
$(watchSubmit);
```

It did not change the behavior inside of the Network tab. Any suggestions as to what could be wrong with either versions of my code OR which version is a better solution? Regardless of whether or not it will solve the aforementioned issue? Thank you.

Comment: in xmlhttp `onreadystatechange`, you call `getDataFromApi` regardless of readystate ... and readystatechange will be triggered *more than once*

Comment: How would I resolve this?

Comment: by only calling `getDataFromApi` at the appropriate time, i.e. `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {`

Comment: I have that in my code.

Comment: yes, you do ... but you run `getDataFromApi` **outside** of that conditional code ... look carefully at the `{}` in the code ... it's not like your have poor indentation, the indentation should make it clear regardless!!!